# vb.net / DataGridView selection?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

On my DataGridView one of the columns is set to a ComboBox. When I make a selection from this ComboBox the CellValue change Event is not triggered. What event is triggered when I do the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as easy as you might wish but with the sample shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on MSDN, it's not that hard.

What you need to do is use your DataGridView's EditingControlShowing event to create a SelectedIndexChanged event for the ComboBox in your DGV.  Your ComboBox's SelectedIndexChanged event will be fired when your ComboBox's SelectedIndex value changes.